# How to change the monitor brightness by X11 RandR extension library?

Tags: c, monitor, xlib, brightness, xrandr

I can simply change my monitor brightness via

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --brightness 0.25
```

Though it is software-only modification, it does the trick anyway. According to the man page, `xrandr` is the primitive command line interface to RandR extension, so it is quiet possible to change my monitor brightness programmatically. However, I didn't find any related API in its header file [`<X11/extensions/Xrandr.h>`](http://www.x.org/archive/current/doc/man/man3/Xrandr.3.xhtml).

How to change the monitor brightness by X11 RandR extension library in C?

Answer (score 2):

yes, xrandr extension, RRChangeOutputProperty request. With libXrandr it's XRRChangeOutputProperty function. See usage example example in [xbacklight source](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/X11apps/X11apps-44/xbacklight/xbacklight-1.1.2/xbacklight.c)

Comment: According to the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/xrandr.1.html), `xbacklight` and `xrandr --brightness` are totally different. `xblacklight` controls hardware brightness if possible, but `xrandr` doesn't.

Comment: which one do you need? both gamma and backlight changed via randr extension calls

Comment: Both gamma and backlight changed is okay, but I want to know how `xrandr` implements for brightness. `xblacklight` doesn't affect my monitor brightness, but `xrandr` does.

Comment: [Xblacklight](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xbacklight/blob/xbacklight-1.2.2/xbacklight.c#L113) (same also for `xrandr --set backlight`) likely doesn't affect your monitor because not every xf86-video driver supports its RandR's [backlight](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/proto/randrproto/tree/randrproto.txt?h=randrproto-1.5.0#n1905) property. `Xrandr`[`--brightness`](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xrandr/blob/xrandr-1.5.0/xrandr.c#L1105) is instead just working "in software" with gamma and colours *internally* to the server, and that's why it always appear to work.

Comment: The brightness is never exposed via XRandR extensions, it might be possible to change this via the CTM output property (Color Transform Matrix) by using a reduced identity matrix to achieve a brightness reduction in all colors but CTM is an "immutable" output property for my driver, maybe newer GPU drivers support it.